# Make normal user as administrator only via patch in window OS

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, permissions

Is there a script to write to the directory.

The user who run the script has not permission to that directory. Also he has not administrator password.

The user can execute the script only, so he can not modify the script to make it do anything.

In Linux  we have "S" permission to do that.

if the user want to modify his password he will use "passwd" program.
this program will read the "shadow" file then modify the user password.

The user has not permission to modify "shadow" file but the program has.

How I can do this in windows OS.

The goal from the first part to make pre-update hook executable for all users.

This is the code for pre-update hook.

```
directory = "C:/Users/Wael.Asad/Desktop/admin"
os.chdir(directory)
os.environ.unsetenv("GIT_DIR")
a= subprocess.run(['git', 'fetch'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
received_text = a.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

This error occurred at this line `os.chdir(directory)`

```
permission Error [WinError 5]  access is denied:"C:/Users/Wael.Asad/Desktop/admin"
```

Comment: Please refresh your memory of how things are supposed to work here by retaking the [tour], and reading through the linked pages within [ask].

Comment: BTW, regarding your edit, did you consider checking the tags you assigned to the question? My reason for asking, is that you've only specified one 'programming'/'scripting' tag, which is [[tag:batch-file]]. I can guarantee that the code box you've now propageted within your question body, does not contain any batch file code, and nowhere in your text body, has one been mentioned. Please follow my previous advice, then try once again to bring your question up to the required on topic standard, and to receive the focused attention you require.

Comment: @Compo the code above is python code, it written in post-update hook.
the git will run this script as batch, So the most important thing is how the OS will execute this script, not script itself.
If you have any modification for the question then please do that. In this way we can make cooperative work.

Comment: My comment AlASAD WAIL, was to assist you to better focus your question to those whom have an interest or specialist knowledge in the area regarding your issue. It is not my role to do that for you, it is your question, and the onus is upon yourself to direct it to the appropriate audiences. If you don't wish to do that, or make any other changes according to the closure notice you received ten hours prior to your comment above, then you're free to leave it as is, safe in the knowledge that closed questions cannot be answered.

Comment: @Compo Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **approach solution** for the dilemma above.
The solution is through **using API to do the above code**.
When the user clicked on the patch file, the batch will make post to API via "CURL" cmd command or "request.post" python command . **The API can access to the directory that user can't**.